# Placing image beside form (with rows)

Tags: html, css

**Note: Using bootstrap**

Here is what I am going for:
[image: Click to view the wanted result]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<style>
.jumbotron
{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.input-group, textarea
{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>

  <div class = "container">
      <div class = "jumbotron text-center">
        <h2>Form</h2>
      </div>

        <form>
        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">First Name:</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Last Name:</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Age:</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
               </div>
              </div>

               <div class = "col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Gender:</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email Address:</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "col-md-4">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Phone Number:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder = "Additional comments"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou38o5z5/)

I'm trying to place an image alongside my form as shown in figure 1.

I've tried various ways: ie. columns within columns, fluid containers etc. 
Using these ways has resulted in the text boxes getting shorter and a big margin between the form and image.

It seems that the rows take up 100% width of the container and width can't be adjusted by using CSS

Any ideas on how to do this?

Also how would I center the form? Can't seem to do that also using methods that work with other elements

Comment: Probably unrelated: You have several extra closing div tags.

Comment: Ah yeah. I edited it there, should be okay now. Just copied a snippet from a project and roughly edited it. Yeah I haven't put the image in the code above. Every implementation where I have put the image code has messed up the width of the text boxes.

Comment: You have not added working jsfiddle link.

Comment: your fiddle link is wrong

Comment: I added the fiddle. What's wrong about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a nested row structure. The outer columns are wrappers for the form structure and the image. The inner columns that contain your form themselves add up to 12.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/busqLLrw/1/)**

Note that I've converted all columns to XS for the demo, and that the two short ones don't fit well at small screen sizes.

```css
.row > div {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>    

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h2>Form</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">First Name:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Last Name:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Age:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Gender:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email Address:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Phone Number:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Hmm i'm gonna make the image only visible from md screens upwards. Could I still use md columns in that case?

Comment: Please upvote all useful answers and accept one if it meets your needs. SO runs on rep points.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Bootstrap's grid** classes and divide your `<form>` section and image section into two parts.

Look at this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbKZXV)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll definitely look more into it. Thanks a lot! I'll mess around with the grid classes for a while.

Comment: @JohnTickle Sure. Let me know if you face any other problem. And you may accept the answer if you think its works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I let you here a [fiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/hvqdp4c7/).

```css
.jumbotron {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.input-group,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img{width:100%}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h2>Form</h2>
    </div>

    <form>
      <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-9">



          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">First Name:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Last Name:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Age:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Gender:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email Address:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Phone Number:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://txtbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/bootstrap.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The thing here is that you should understand that Bootstrap use a grid system made by 12 columns. When you declare a row, you have to keep in mind that it has 12 gaps to fill with your columns.

To implement a layout like yours, you shouldn't try to fit an element, like your image, which takes several rows height. In spite of that, it's better to create two columns, one for the inputs and another one for the image. Then inside the filed's column, just add as many rows as you need and fill then with the necessary columns, always keeping in mind that you have to fill 12 gaps.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't entirely clear on the span of rows. However, this has cleared it up a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I help. If some of the answers were useful to you, you can leave an upvote, and if one solved your question, you should mark it.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to take one row and two columns(or you can add divide manually with col-6) and bootstrap will adjust its width and[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgkdL.png) with div, you can add one form and your image each side and it will pop up perfectly.